# Rendering messes up my image but its correct in viewport. please help

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I have when rendering in blender.
So my Viewport looks like
[image: normal and correct]
But when I render it looks like
[image: layers muddled and mixed up]
If you could please give me some advice on how to fix it I would be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Hmm... this is not supposed to happen. Which blender version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a copy of the donut and the icing in the collection named **archive**. It's hidden in the viewport only ("eye" icon) but not hidden for rendering. The ojbects are rendered overlapping. That's what you see on the final render.

**Uncheck the checkmark of the **archive** collection in the *Outliner*** and all objects in there are completely hidden in the viewport and rendering in Blender 2.9x.

(Blender 2.8x users must disable the rendering with a *Restriction Toggle* as shown here: [Image Texture completely washed out in Render, but not in Viewport Shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210503/image-texture-completely-washed-out-in-render-but-not-in-viewport-shading/210509#210509))